# Как искать в пдф на Google drive?

Tags: python, api

С помощью python 3 я хочу написать программу, которая будет искать файл на гугл диске по содержимому внутри .pdf файла и получать ссылку на открытие этого файла.
Мой текущий код пока только возвращает список всех файлов на гугл диске.

```
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'token.json'
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
results = service.files().list(pageSize=10,
                               fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType, exportLinks)").execute()
pprint(results)
```

Передавая exportLinks в fields я почему-то получаю ссылку только на gsheets файл.
Прошу помощи, как я могу в коде передать строку, чтобы я искал эту строку в содержимом в файлах на гугл диске и получал на него ссылку?